# How to do logging at function entry, inside and exit in Python

Tags: python, logging

I'd like to be able to do simple and consistent logging in my code using the Python logging facility.

**I am able to do the following:**

1. I'd like all existing/future module and functions to have "Entering ..." and "Done ..." log messages.
2. I don't want to add the same code snippet to defining logging parameters (shown below `don't want to add everywhere`) in every function definition.
3. I want the `log.info(...)` etc constructs to work in any function I define in the project hierarchy.

**What doesn't work / I don't know how to do it:**

1. I'd like to avoid defining the same `@log` decorator in every existing/new module that I write.

```py
# don't want to add everywhere
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)-20s - %(levelname)-5s - %(message)s'
LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=LEVEL)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

**Sample code from my Flask project:**

```py
# app/__init__.py
from a import b  # various other imports required for app
import logging
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)-20s - %(levelname)-5s - %(message)s'
LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=LEVEL)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# ... various other app init code
from app import views, models
```

```py
#app/views.py
from c import d  # various other imports required for the module

def logger(fn):
    from functools import wraps
    import inspect
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global log
        log = logging.getLogger(inspect.stack()[1][3])
        log.info('About to run %s' % fn.__name__)

        out = fn(*args, **kwargs)

        log.info('Done running %s' % fn.__name__)
        # Return the return value
        return out
    return wrapper

    @app.route('/this_func')
    @logger
    def this_func():
        log.info('I am doing logging without having to do bunch of definitions.')
        # some more code

    @app.route('/that_func')
    @logger
    def that_func():
        log.info('Yet more logging without having to do bunch of definitions.')
        log.info('I can simply refer to the log object and be done with it.')
        # some more code
```

Comment: "Ideally, I should be able to do something like this"... what about "this" isn't working? What's your question?

Comment: Right, that log_calls decorator looks like it's doing the job already.

Comment: You're calling `basicConfig()` lots of times. Don't do that. It should only be called once from `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: @VinaySajip can you elaborate?  Where is basicConfig()?  Also, I thought __main__ is only called when module is executed directly, e.g., python view.py not when `from app import view`

Comment: Tried to clarify the question as only one challenge remains: how to avoid defining the `@logger` decorator in every module.

Comment: @HanSooloo Just write the function in another file and import it.

Answer (score 14):

The final setup that worked for me was the following:

```py
# At the beginning of every .py file in the project
def logger(fn):
    from functools import wraps
    import inspect
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        log = logging.getLogger(fn.__name__)
        log.info('About to run %s' % fn.__name__)

        out = fn(*args, **kwargs)

        log.info('Done running %s' % fn.__name__)
        # Return the return value
        return out
    return wrapper

# Do the following section only in application's app/__init__.py
# Other files will pick it up from here.
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s'

# Change logging LEVEL according to debugging needs.
# Probably better to read this from a config or a launch parameter.
LEVEL = logging.DEBUG

logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=LEVEL)
# Up to here only for app/__init__.py

# This section again at the beginning of every .py file
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info('Entered module: %s' % __name__)
```

Now, add a `@logger` decorator to every function definition in the module:

```py
@logger
def do_something():
    print('doing really useful stuff.')
```

Comment: where does the apply func come in?

Comment: @JeffTilton I've not had the chance to try this myself but the apply function would most likely refer to the function that is being wrapped by the `@logger` decorator. In this example, that would be `do_something`.

Comment: @JeffTilton `apply` was used i Python 2, now you can use `fn(*args, **kwargs)` instead.

Comment: I have been using essentially this for several years. It works fine in operation, but during debugging it's a minor PITA when stepping into an @logger decorated function. Worth it, but I'd really like an EVEN better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using contextlib with exception handling.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
import logging
from time import time 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(processName)s | %(thread)d | %(message)s')
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@contextmanager
def EEL(methodDescr, raiseExcp=False):
  '''EEL = Entry Exit Log'''
  log.info(f"Starting function: {methodDescr}")
  start = time()
  try:
    yield
  except Exception as ex:
    log.exception("Got exception")
  finally:
    end = time()
    log.info(f"Time taken by {methodDescr}: {end-start}")
```

Usage:

```
@EEL("Test method")
def test():
  x = 0
  for i in range(1,1000000):
    x = x + i
```

Output:

```
2020-09-22 11:09:17,418 | INFO | MainProcess | 139709531875200 | Starting function: Test method
2020-09-22 11:09:17,484 | INFO | MainProcess | 139709531875200 | Time taken by Test method: 0.06573295593261719
```

Comment: Whenever you're timing something in python you should use `time.perf_counter()` instead of `time()`.

Comment: From this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25787875/2612429), it appears that perf_counter returns unit-less measurement, that cannot be related to real-world time and may vary across different systems. If that's true, your suggestion might be fine if one is comparing performance on a single machine only.

Comment: Solid point. It still works on the distributed systems I work with. You need your logging statements to contain something like a process id, thread id, or a request id. Something that lets you establish a timeline being read over a log file or log stream.

Having the UTC time can be useful but when I'm doing performance comparisons I find it more useful to have the time between calls be in milliseconds.