# python - how to log everything without instrumentation

Tags: python, logging, pycharm

I want to log **everything:**

1. Function entered + values of parameters + function exited
2. Result of every assignment or operation
3. etc.

Is it possible to log "everything" in a Python execution without instrumenting the code?

Since things are executing in a VM, it should be possible to configure this at the VM level (hopefully?).

I'm using Pycharm but I could do it via commandline it it's necessary.

There's this existing question: [How to do logging at function entry, inside and exit in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435488/how-to-do-logging-at-function-entry-inside-and-exit-in-python) but it doesn't address how to log the result of variable assignments.

Comment: whoever voted to close: could you at least tell me WHY it's a bad question?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the [`trace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) module and/or perhaps the [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) module. They may not give you everything you need, but it would be a starting point. The `logging` module doesn't work at such a low level as you seem to want.

Comment: Doesn't look like it keeps track of variables.